Canon AE-1 aperture doesn't close down past f/4
So my Canon AE-1 Program aperture doesn't close down past f/4 when using the DOF preview. I've tried a different lens and same thing so it is a problem with the camera. Both the lenses I have are 50mm 1.8 FD lenses. I think the aperture lever has lost it's strength like others have had happen.
My question is - is this fixable? ...and will it limit my aperture to f/4 when shooting or is it just for DOF preview?
Here is a video of trying to close down to f/22: https://streamable.com/2st6jp
Thank you.

Have you read the manual for your camera? I'm not familiar with the model, but I just took a quick look... https://www.cameramanuals.org/canon_pdf/canon_ae-1_program.pdf. Go to page 52 and read the big red warning box. This is an old (and apparently finicky) camera. Follow all instructions exactly as in the manual. Post an answer here if you figure out exactly what's going on - it will help others.

All this testing I did without the camera film advance lever being cocked, as soon as I cocked it worked fine!

That's the "on-off" switch.
